# Outlook clients not connecting in one office only

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook

Our company has three offices, and the main one is having problems with Outlook clients (both 2010 and 2013) unable to connect to hosted exchange server on MessageSteam. They spend a while "trying to connect" and then drop to "disconnected". The clients stopped connecting about 4pm yesterday (Tues 9th Feb) and are still offline this morning.

What we have tried so far:

- restarted Outlook
- restarted PC
- set to "offline" then set back to online
- installed windows updates
- checked DNS resolution: server https://cas.messageexchange.com/ is resolving fine
- checked service status on the MessageStream site (no issues) - it works at other locations
- a phone on wifi can't connect to Exchange, but on gsm network it can connect
- restarted the router
- restarted the local server that hosts DHCP, DNS

So now I've run out of ideas for things to check. Suggestions as to how to diagonose the problem are most welcome.

Comment: It could be some type of routing issue between the network providers.  I have seen that many times before.  Try contacting the ISP?

Comment: What happens when you do a tracert to the CAS from a working office vs from the non-working office?  If there is a routing issue you may see responses drop off at a certain hop in the path.

Comment: Does sound like a routing issue. Is there wifi on the workstation that you can tap into a hotspot to isolate the routing from that office entirely? For diagnostic, on the workstation, hold-Ctrl, right-click Outlook icon from the systemTray and test E-Mail AutoConfiguration to see if it's any help

Comment: Thanks for all the comments - we tried connecting a different router on a different ISP (there are three connections here fortunately) and we have got  connectivity back - suggesting something on the router or the ISP.

Comment: @Quango Please consider answering your own question and close this question off

Answer (score 0):

There was no conclusive fault found and the problem went away when we used a different DSL link on a different router, so it may have been an issue with the existing link or the router configuration.